# Translate Shipping and handling, grandtotal, subtotal for PDF invoice, from backend in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, invoice, localisation, pdf

How can I translate the "Shipping & Handling", "Subtotal", "Grand Total" from the PDF invoice that is generated after you press the button PRINT in the backend. The invoice needs to be translated. And those in particular are not translated. Where are the files that contains this information?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding adding your translation strings to your theme file :

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/i18n/en_US.csv
```

Example :

```
"Grand Total","Big Total"
```

*Note : be careful with spaces in some translations*